# Malloc of 2 bytes gives issues

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I am trying to use a malloc of short, something like

```
typedef union _SOME_STRUCT_ {

   struct {

     USHORT u:4;
     USHORT v:4;
     USHORT w:4;

   } x;

   USHORT word;

} SOME_STRUCT, *PSOME_STRUCT;

PSOME_STRUCT p = malloc (sizeof (SOME_STRUCT));

if (p) {

    p->x.u = 0;
}

free (p); // **** RANDOMLY CRASHING HERE ****
```

I am debugging for a couple of days and clueless,

Note(edited): Linux, and gcc Version 3.4.6 20060404

---

**ISSUE FOUND USING VALGRIND**

But then, I would like to document it here so that my fellow developers might be aware of such a situation ...

I had actually defined the structure as

```
typedef union _SOME_STRUCT_ {

   struct {

     USHORT u:4;
     USHORT v:4;
     USHORT w:4;

   } x;

   USHORT word;

} ALBUM, *PALBUM;
```

and some-where else in the code I had also defined

```
#define ALBUM "album"
```

And so, sizeof (ALBUM) was referring to the #define value rather than the typedef and hence the issue.

The thing that amazes me is,

**Is this allowed in C?**

---

Comment: It runs perfectly fine for me on Windows XP/MinGW...

Comment: Linux, and gcc Version 3.4.6 20060404.

Comment: Post a full compilable c file that exhibits the error (so that others can try to reproduce it), not just the above snippet.

Comment: I just tried it on Ubuntu/ gcc Version 4.2.4 .  It worked... Even though my gcc is a newer version, I suggest you post the entire code, as lothar asked.

Comment: Tried on cygwin gcc 3.4.4 - works.

Please post an executable code and complete compiler command line.

Comment: Is it *randomly* crashing here, or *always* crashing here, for a random reason?

Comment: To answer your question "is this allowed in C?": yes  it is. You pass any size you wish to malloc(). It's up to you to mind this kind of issue. And sizeof operator won't look where it called from to warn you when the size it is computing is not a struct's size. Glad to see Valgrind help you. That tool often helps a lot! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass your program through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) , an open source program and totaly free, maybe it could help you to see where is the issue. Don't forget to compile with debug symbols: gcc -g [etc] .

Hope this help..

Comment: I gave this a shot, and valgrind said, "no leaks are possible."

Comment: I didn't use Valgring for a while, but if your program crash while valgring execute it, it must at least provide you a core dump. Did your program crashed down ? And do you have a core file now ? If so , pass it to gdb. It could give you more vital information.

Answer (score 3):

This version of the code works for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define USHORT unsigned short

typedef union _SOME_STRUCT_ {
    struct {
        USHORT u:4;
        USHORT v:4;
        USHORT w:4;
    } x;
    USHORT word;
} SOME_STRUCT, *PSOME_STRUCT;

int
main(int c, char *argv[])
{
    PSOME_STRUCT p = malloc (sizeof (SOME_STRUCT));

    if (p) {
        p->x.u = 0;
    }

    free (p); // **** Properly exiting after this ****
}
```

---

This is GDB debug from a Cygwin on Windows XP.

```
(gdb) p/x sizeof(PSOME_STRUCT)
$1 = 0x4
(gdb) p/x sizeof(p)
$2 = 0x4
(gdb) p/x sizeof(*p)
$3 = 0x2
(gdb) n
23              if (p) {
(gdb) p/x *p
$4 = {x = {u = 0xc, v = 0x4, w = 0x3}, word = 0x534c}
```

Ignore the values in $4, data is uninitialized.
Program exited normally.

Do you have something else in the code besides these lines?

Edit: and, free(0); is a valid operation.

Comment: Indeed - is there anything malloc'ed next to struct?

Answer (score 2):

Might be an alignment issue. Does it still crash if you do something like this:

```
   struct {
     USHORT u:4;
     USHORT v:4;
     USHORT w:4;
     USHORT  :4;
   } x;
```

Comment: Outside of a code-gen bug, the compiler should be generating properly aligned data structures for this code.  The remaining : 4 is unnecessary since the USHORT word in the union forces the struct to be 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the code but something that is happening before or in another thread.

I would reduce sections of the program until it stops crashing and then add it back in step by step until you figure out what section is causing this. Depending on the OS/Platform you could also try some memory checking tools, valgrind/_crtdebug etc..

Answer (score 1):

If this issue is happening where you could debug it you could start your debug session with a call to memcheck.

A cause for a crash for memory is most often heap or freeing the same pointer twice.

Answer (score 1):

You're unconditionally calling free() without checking if the malloc succeeded, so if the malloc failed and p is a NULL pointer, then you're calling free(NULL).

Move the free inside the if (p) block.

This might not be the cause of the crashes, and shouldn't be if not memory-constrained, but is a bug nonetheless.

Added later: doh, free(NULL) is explicitly allowed, per http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/free.html -- sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing stuff in between the malloc and free, you could be overrunning a different array by accident and corrupting your own stack

(if 'p' doesn't happen to be in a register, and you overrun a statically-allocated array and hit the place on the stack where 'p' is stored, you will then later attempt to free random crap, hence the segfault)

Answer (score 0):

What if you put free(p) in your if?  Maybe (unlikely) malloc is failing...

Comment: free(NULL) is valid (defined as a no-op), and should not result in a crash.

Comment: delete NULL is valid, I am not sure about free(NULL)

Comment: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/free.html "If ptr is a null pointer, no action shall occur."